# Run Search on Webpage Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

I'm trying to dynamically submit a search form on BBB (Better Business Bureau) then load the results as if you were to go to the web page and enter the search criteria yourself. So far I dont have much, but...

```
$.post('https://www.bbb.org/search/', {input:"car", location:"New York, NY"}, function(data){ $( "#results" ).empty().append( data ); });
```

Basically I send the input and location and attempt the load the results in to a div container. I can load the results in to the current page OR just re-route to the page that would load had you manually ran the search. Any ideas on how to do this? I know pages like youtube have search api's for developers but BBB does not (to my knowledge)

Answer (score 1):

You can form the query string for the main search page with "input" and "location". e.g for input : "car" and location : "New York, NY" query strings looks like this

```
queryString = type=name&input=car&location=New York,NY&tobid=&filter=business&source=bbbse&default-source=bbbad&radius=&country=&language=&codeType="
```

append this query string to the url. "https://www.bbb.org/search/?" + queryString

which is equivalent to https://www.bbb.org/search/?type=name&input=car&location=New+York%2C+NY&tobid=&filter=combined&source=bbbse&default-source=bbbad&radius=&country=USA&language=en&codeType=YPPA

Now you can set browser window.location (javascript) equal to above url which will route you to desired page with search results.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the special characters (easily) when you do it this way? I.e, the comma character become weird text ("%2C")

Comment: javascript will take care of that on its own.

var URL = "https://www.bbb.org/search/?" + "?type=name&input=car&location=New York, NY&tobid=&filter=business&source=bbbse&default-source=bbbad&radius=&country=&language=&codeType="

url has spaces above , 
but when you set window.location = url , it ll be automatically encoded